# Button dropdown links don't work on mobile (android, iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4550

This issue says it's fixed; I uploaded bootstrap.js 2.2.2 and it still doesn't work.

Is there additional code or files that need to be written?

The dropup doesn't work on an iPad.

I saw the previous Stack Overflow questions and work arounds. But since this issue is supposed to be fixed in 2.2.2 I don't want to be adding code that's not necessary.

Comment: Whoever downvote it, comment on it as well to let the user know why the question gets downvoted

Comment: I have this problem a month ago, y fix with this: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4550#issuecomment-7987654

Comment: The issue was with the folder structure and not code. Thanks for the help..